# Efficiently read values around another value in a 2D Array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, 2d

I'm busy trying to write a version of Minesweeper in Python 3.5, and the code I have here is designed to look through each value in a 2-Dimensional Array I created as the Game board, and check to see how many mines (signified by "O") are surrounding it. It works, but I feel the code is too clunky. Is there a function in python that does this, or is there a function I could write that would simplify it?

The if statements are there to first off check if the value is in the array, so that out of range does not occur, and then to check at the location.

```
for x in range(len(array)):

        for y in range(len(array[0])):

            if array[x][y] != "O":

                counter = 0

                if (x - 1 >= 0) and (array[x-1][y] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (x + 1 < len(array)) and (array[x+1][y] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (y - 1 >= 0) and (array[x][y+1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (y + 1 < len(array)) and (array[x][y+1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (x - 1 >= 0) and (y - 1 >= 0) and (array[x-1][y-1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (x - 1 >= 0) and (y + 1 < len(array)) and (array[x-1][y+1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (x + 1 < len(array)) and (y - 1 >= 0) and (array[x+1][y-1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                if (x + 1 < len(array)) and (y + 1 < len(array)) and (array[x+1][y+1] == "O"):

                    counter += 1

                array[x][y] = counter
```

Comment: What values can an array element take? I take `if array[x][y] != 0` to mean that it's not an empty cell and therefore the number in it would signify how many mines are around it. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Also, can you use numpy?

Comment: I meant to write != "O", signifying it is not a mine. I updated it. I am not that  experienced, and although I have heard of numpy, I didn't know it could do something like this.

Comment: That's good, it makes more sense now. Numpy isn't necessary to solve this problem (and it would require you to install it if you don't have it already), but it can make multidimensional slicing convenient and many operations can be vectorised, which might lead to performance improvements over iterating lists of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function after array[x][y] != 0

```
def checkNeighbours(x,y,matrix):
    neighbourValues = [matrix[x_][y_] for x_ in range(x-1,x+2) for y_ in range(y-1,y+2)
                       if (0 <= x_ < len(matrix) and 0 <= y_ < len(matrix) and (x_ != x or y_ != y))]
    return neighbourValues.count('O')
```

Comment: The code works perfectly, but how does it work? Sorry, but I do not understand the code within the NeighbourValues assignment.

Comment: @Dova That line is a list comprehension. The `for x_ in range(x-1,x+2) for y_ in range(y-1,y+2)` generates the 3x3 window around the cell of interest, including the cell itself and the conditionals in the if statement ignore any out of bounds coordinates (the cell at (0, 0) has only 3 neighbours + itself). The condition `x_ != x or y_ != y` excludes the central cell, but it'd be fine to drop this condition since we guarantee that it won't be a mine with `if array[x][y] != 'O'`.

Comment: @Dova The underscores are to create new names, namely `x_` and `y_` so that they don't overwrite `x` and `y` since you still need them.

Comment: Thanks! Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

A possible numpy based solution would be like this. Check the comments to make sure you understand what they're making:

```
 import numpy as np

 m = np.random.randint(0,2,(5,5)).astype('bool')

 print(m)  # game matrix

 # Running all cels in matrix
 for i in range(m.shape[0]):
     for j in range(m.shape[1]):
         # clip will ensure you'll never have a value below 0 for indexes which
         # is important at the borders of the game.
         c = np.count_nonzero(m[np.clip(i-1,0,m.shape[0]):i+2,np.clip(j-1,0,m.shape[1]):j+2])
         if m[i,j]:
             c = c - 1 # ensure you are not couting the cell where you are in.
         print('FOR POSITION ',i,j,' FOUND ',c,' MINES.')
```

The result was this:

```
[[False False False  True False]
 [ True  True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False]]
FOR POSITION  0 0  FOUND  2  MINES.
FOR POSITION  0 1  FOUND  2  MINES.
FOR POSITION  0 2  FOUND  3  MINES.
FOR POSITION  0 3  FOUND  3  MINES.
FOR POSITION  0 4  FOUND  3  MINES.
FOR POSITION  1 0  FOUND  4  MINES.
FOR POSITION  1 1  FOUND  5  MINES.
FOR POSITION  1 2  FOUND  6  MINES.
FOR POSITION  1 3  FOUND  6  MINES.
FOR POSITION  1 4  FOUND  5  MINES.
FOR POSITION  2 0  FOUND  6  MINES.
FOR POSITION  2 1  FOUND  8  MINES.
FOR POSITION  2 2  FOUND  7  MINES.
FOR POSITION  2 3  FOUND  7  MINES.
FOR POSITION  2 4  FOUND  5  MINES.
FOR POSITION  3 0  FOUND  6  MINES.
FOR POSITION  3 1  FOUND  9  MINES.
FOR POSITION  3 2  FOUND  8  MINES.
FOR POSITION  3 3  FOUND  7  MINES.
FOR POSITION  3 4  FOUND  4  MINES.
FOR POSITION  4 0  FOUND  4  MINES.
FOR POSITION  4 1  FOUND  6  MINES.
FOR POSITION  4 2  FOUND  5  MINES.
FOR POSITION  4 3  FOUND  4  MINES.
FOR POSITION  4 4  FOUND  2  MINES.
```

Comment: The question has been slightly amended. The OP intended to write `if array[x][y] != 'O'`, so you want to iterate over non-bomb cells and count the surrounding bombs. To reflect that I think you'd need `window = m[np.clip()...]; c = np.sum(window == 'O')`. No need to discount `m[i,j]` because you exclude exploring those squares anyway.

Comment: Additionally, instead of using `np.clip()`, it's faster with `i0 = max(i-1, 0); j0 = max(j-1, 0); window = m[i0:i+2,j0:j+2]`.

Comment: Oh, I just used the loop for demonstration purposes. In theory the code inside the loop would be in function to be called at any time, in any place. Agreed for the max instead of clip, since we don't really need to clip for a maximum (although the function requires it). And it's more readable.

Comment: What does the "m" assignment do? This also works, thanks!

Comment: Sure. I was just pointing out the slight discrepancies with the exact desires of the OP, in case he didn't know how to modify your idea to his needs. That said, I would use this code inside the for loops as is without putting it in a function, or else you'd incur the cost of calling a function for each cell. Unless, of course, this code needs to be executed in more than one places.

Comment: @Dova It creates a 2D array with random 0 or 1 values. I just transformed into bool (True or False) in the end.

Comment: @Reti43 I don't think the loss of performance is significant for the minesweeper game. Personally I would put it inside a function; if anything but readability. But I agree that for more critical problems (million cells minesweeper?) the approach would be another.